# Add Footnote caption underneath of Table in every page using Flextable

Tags: r

I want to add a footnote caption under the table using Flextable. I have output of 10 pages. I want to add text under the table in every page. I have tried this code, but getting the footnote in last page only.

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)
myft <- add_footer_lines(myft, "a short caption")
myft <- align(myft, i = 1, part = "header", align = "left")
```

It will be great help. Please suggest any alternative method

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?